# Error authenticating with the refresh token due to: expired access/refresh token when I try to retrieve/deploy source from org

Tags: salesforcedx

I have a project in Sandbox in Salesforce. Every day when I try to retrieve source from my org I got this error: [image]

How to resolve this issue?

The thing is that if I download and create project from scratch then It works but only till the next day. The next day this token automatically expires or something. I am not sure what is the problem, and I start to have this error again. So how to fix this so I don't to have to create a new project every morning?

My sfdx version : sfdx-cli/7.108.0 win32-x64 node-v14.17.1

sfdx update didn't seem to help.

Comment: Is there something that’s modifying some files in .sfdx folder? Also can you add your CLI version (sfdx —version) will give you the version

Comment: Could you please tell how to add my CLI version and where should I add it?

Comment: Execute sfdx --version and add the version to question

Comment: Added to the question

Comment: Run sfdx update so the CLI moves to latest build

Comment: sfdx update helped but just for some time. Not it is not working again.

Comment: Could you open a case with Salesforce support to get it investigated? It seems like an issue with your computer.

Comment: We work on this project in our team. Everybody in the team has the same issue.

Comment: Still an issue, I miss the eclipse days, one step forward 10 steps back

Answer (score 40):

It happened to me every time we refresh our dev org, so you can try to logout your user with the command:

```
sf org logout --target-org username@org.com.dev
```

And then you have to authorize again the org.

As malte wrote in the comment, you have also to reopen VS Code.

Comment: This helped. But I additionally had to close/reopen the project / VSCode.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This helped!
To Summarise,

1. Logout using the command: sfdx force:auth:logout -u OrgAlias 
(eg: sfdx force:auth:logout -u testDev)

2. Close the VSCode.

3. Reopen the VSCode and go to the terminal

4.Re-authorize using the login command: sfdx force:auth:web:login -a OrgAlias
(eg: sfdx force:auth:web:login -a testDev)

Comment: Logging out is not necessary. Authorize again and use the same alias. Next, close and re-open VSCode. That's all that's needed.

Answer (score 12):

Even I faced the same issue.
Solution: I updated the sfdx cli after I logged out and closed the IDE opened again authorized it. It worked

--- Just restarting VS code after authorizing works also (no need to reinstall the cli)

Answer (score 6):

It is not necessary to log out of the org using sfdx first. This solution works every time.

1. Run SFDX:Authorize an Org. Use the same Alias as you did when you initially setup the org.
2. Restart VsCode

Your deploy/retrieve will now succeed.

Comment: Reauth AND restart...  Reauth alone doesn't work, for some reason VSCode must be restarted as well.  I suppose it is a problem with the SF extensions caching the token, regardless whether the CLI has updated them.

Answer (score 3):

None of the solutions above helped me to solve this issue, unfortunately.
To solve it I had to :

1. Use the commander above : `sfdx force:auth:logout -u username/alias`
2. Remove/Delete the ".sfdx" folder in the Project
3. Authorise the Org again

And I was able to retrieve the sources after that.

Hope it'll help

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I face this issue I execute the following command and it gets resolved:

```
sfdx force:org:open -u ORG_ALIAS
```

For `ORG_ALIAS` either use the org that your are trying to retrieve/deploy metadata from, or your DevHub's alias in case you are doing something where the DevHub is needed (e.g. something with packages).

Comment: I tried this workaround with a sandbox and it did not work. I got the same error response: Error authenticating with the refresh token due to: expired access/refresh token